# Subview loaded inside UIView does not constrain to UIView bounds

Tags: xcode, swift3

I have created the following scene:

[Application scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l4ND.png)

The scene contains a stackView with all other views contained inside of it. The grey area is a UIView which gets three subviews added to it during viewDidLoad. I want each of these views to fill the UIView and be constrained to its bounds. When one of the three buttons is clicked, the corresponding view is brought to the front of for display. The issue I am facing is that the subviews are not being constrained to the UIView. I've tried quite a few different options but cannot seem to get the effect I am looking for. The red in the following image is the background of one of the loaded subviews.

[iPhone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWUln.png)

On larger devices, the subviews overextend the boundary on the right side as well. How do I constrain the subViews to my UIView boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the frame of the 3 views you want to be constrained with the bounds of the grey superview. This can be done in `layoutSubviews` of the grey view or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the viewController.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    subview0.frame = greyView.bounds
    subview1.frame = greyView.bounds
    subview2.frame = greyView.bounds
}
```

or within the custom class for the grey view (if you have defined a custom class)

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    subview0.frame = bounds
    subview1.frame = bounds
    subview2.frame = bounds
}
```

Can also be done by using constraints to constrain the subviews to their superview.

Comment: Perfect. Works Great.